# Pushed local branch shows as stale in remote

Tags: git

I'm working on a contribution to an open-source project. I have a branch with my stuff that I have pushed to my GitHub repository, and I can see it there (https://github.com/sedulam/CASSANDRA-13990). I'm pulling directly from the project source repository.
However, when I do `git remote show origin` it shows as stale:

```
laptop@pandaria:~/git/cassandra$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/sedulam/CASSANDRA-13990.git
  HEAD branch: trunk
  Remote branches:
    cassandra-1.0                   tracked
    cassandra-1.1                   tracked
    cassandra-1.2                   tracked
    cassandra-2.0                   tracked
    cassandra-2.1                   tracked
    cassandra-2.2                   tracked
    cassandra-3.0                   tracked
    cassandra-3.11                  tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/13990-trunk stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    trunk                           tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    13990-trunk merges with remote 13990-trunk
    trunk       merges with remote trunk
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    trunk pushes to trunk (local out of date)

laptop@pandaria:~/git/cassandra$ git push
Everything up-to-date

laptop@pandaria:~/git/cassandra$ git status
On branch 13990-trunk
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/13990-trunk'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How do I link my local 13990-trunk to the branch I have on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origin` refers in your case to `gitbox.apache.org`, not `github.com`.

Do add `github.com` as a remote:

```
git remote add github https://github.com/sedulam/CASSANDRA-13990.git
```

And fetch (`git fetch github`), in order to get `/refs/remotes/github/13990-trunk`.

You can then create a local branch [tracking the remote branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--t):

```
git checkout --track -b 13990-trunk github/13990-trunk
```

Comment: I thought that by adding my GitHub as the push URL, it would be enough. What's the meaning of having `Push URL` to my GitHub, since it's under `origin` (Apache)?

Comment: Technically `origin` now refers to *both*, one at a time. @PedroGordo: what it means is that `git push` goes to the push URL `https://github.com/sedulam/CASSANDRA-13990.git`, while `git fetch` goes to the fetch URL `https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra.git`. Presumably these are two different repositories, with different branch-head commits and maybe even different commit-graphs.

Comment: @torek So can I say that the preferential method would be to leave the `origin` upstream alone, and instead always create a new remote to push to, instead of messing with the URLs?

Comment: @PedroGordo https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem: it would push to GitHub but does not remove the old remote tracking branch from the first remote.

Comment: @PedroGordo that's what I would do, especially for this case. Using a separate fetch vs push URL rarely makes a lot of sense.